# Resource for learning recursion and induction over lists and trees?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, induction, bibliography

I am writing a course on Functional Programming and one of the modules in the course covers lists, and another one cover trees. Both modules center on recursion and induction over these datatypes. I am seeking some material that covers these topics in order to include it as part of the course's bibliography.

Can anyone please link to a good resource (preferably a book) where I can find these topics explained?

Answer (score 1):

May be [The Craft of Functional Programming](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/sjt/Haskell_craft/toc.html)